# controller script running in studio or deployment

Tags: crafter-cms

Is there a way in a groovy controller script to know is it's running in the studio or in deployment server?

I have code that will added data into the model for demo in studio mode while in deployment that data will come from a REST service call.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's an easy way to know if a Groovy script is running in authoring (preview) or in delivery (live). Crafter provides a global variable called `modePreview`. This variable is basically a boolean flag that indicates if the current environment is authoring, or in other words, if Crafter Engine is running in preview mode. So you can do something as simple as `if (modePreview) { RUN CODE }` in Groovy to run code that only needs to be run in the authoring environment.

Comment: is this documented somewhere?